# Using apropos command with -a to search multiple keywords on CentOS 7

Tags: command-line, search, man, options

I'm running **CentOS 7.0 build 1503**. I'm trying to search for commands I don't know the name of by searching the man descriptions for **multiple** keywords using **AND** (e.g. search for a command containing the both words "create" and "group" in the description).

So I came across the command **apropos** (which is an alias for man -k). The default behaviour when given multiple keywords is to return any command matching any of the keywords, which isn't what I want. According to the man page the option **-a specifies using AND**, to return matches only when all words match.

But this isn't what I'm seeing in practice, so I need some help here - e.g. using Centos 7, if I do:

```
apropos create user
```

I see a huge list of commands, seemingly matching any command with create or user in the description, as expected. Noting the list includes an entry for the command '**useradd (8) - create a new user...**'.

If I do:

```
apropos -a create user
```

I only get 2 commands (environ and open). This is what I'm confused by - I would expect it to return the command 'useradd (8) - create a new user', because i can see from the previous search that command does contain those words in the description. Also the 2 returned commands don't obviously seem to be anything about creating users. What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it's something embarrassingly obvious, for that I apologise in advance.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using? I get `newusers`,`pam_mkhomedir`, `rmsginit` and `useradd` for `apropos -a create user` on Debian.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. I'm using Centos 7 (build 1503), just installed today and have done yum update. I get newusers when I do 'apropos newusers', but not when i do 'apropos -a create user'

Comment: Well, then the man page probably doesn't contain that string. What does `man newusers | grep create | grep  user` return?

Comment: Looks like it's fixed in more recent versions of man-db. CentOS 7 has version 2.6.3, from 2012, and I can reproduce the bug. Version 2.6.7.1 seems to have a working `-a` option. As a workaround, you can do `comm -12 <(apropos create|sort) <(apropos user|sort)`

Comment: Thanks Mark, if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. I'd like to fix. Just downloaded 2.6.7.1 from savannah project but I get stuck at ./configure - libpipeline version is too old. Am I about to go down a rabbit hole of upgrading dependencies (I'm new to Linux, I think the windows term is DLL hell)?

Answer (score 2):

The `apropos` command reads from a cache. It's possible that recently-installed man pages are not yet referenced in that cache. Generally the cache is updated either after each package installation or in a cron job, I don't know how it's set up on CentOS.

To update the cache, run `mandb`. There may be a prefered way to run it on your distribution (e.g. as a dedicated user), see if you have a system crontab entry (e.g. `/etc/cron.daily/man-db` or a line in `/etc/crontab`) and if you do, run that instead of calling `mandb` directly.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks for the info - unfortunately running mandb didn't help things. I believe this is a bug in the version I have (see Mark's comment) and as I'm still super new to Linux cron looks a bit too gnarly for me right now! I'm on a home play VM so I'm not too worried about screwing my system and starting again.